# How to open a ContextMenu on RelativeLayout click, using custom Adapter

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I am attempting to recreate the ListView seen in Android 4.0 Music player, which allows access to a `ContextMenu` through clicking an area on the right of the row:

[image: Screenshot of the Music Player ListView in Android ICS]

To do this I am creating complex ListFragment rows using RelativeLayout. This has been fairly easy to recreate:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/row_select">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/grabber"
    android:layout_width="22dip"
    android:layout_height="110dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/grabber" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"


    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/grabber"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/playlist_context"

    android:textAppearance="@style/Title"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"

    android:textAppearance="@style/Subtitle"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingBottom="10dip"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle"

    android:textAppearance="@style/body"
    android:lines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"  />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/playlist_context"
    android:layout_width="26dip"
    android:layout_height="110dip"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/row_select">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playlist_context"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle" />

</RelativeLayout>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hidden_id"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also use my own custom `CursorAdapter` to populate each row, using `bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c)`.

I now need to show a `ContextMenu` for a row when that row's `R.id.playlist_context` is clicked. This clickable area is highlighted in red in the screenshot above. In `bindView` I can set an `onClickListener`:

```
//Watch for the context menu click
((RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.playlist_context)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("PlaylistCursorAdapter", "Clicked something");
        }
    });
```

This works, logging "Clicked something" every time I click that wee `RelativeLayout`.

I can also implement a ContextMenu which appears on long-press, by using `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` in the `ListFragment`. That's well documented.

---

So I can capture the click, in my custom adapter.*✓* And I can create and open a `ContextMenu`, in my `ListFragment`.*✓*

How do I consolidate this, i.e. how can I make the `ContextMenu` show up when you click on the `RelativeLayout`?

Thanks for any help!